# How to mix class="form-horizontal" with ordinary form elements in a bootstrap form?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I mix `class="form-horizontal"` in a **single** form with form elements that don't are displayed as horizontal? The tag is intended to reside in the `<form>`-tag according to the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp).

Conflicting part (form-horizontal-tag conflicts with the rest of the form:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/registrieren" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="usr">Surname:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vorname" name="vorname">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="usr">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="usr">Street:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="strasse" name="strasse">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

A working horizontal form:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'd like to have everything into one single form, but the surname and name beside each other.

Whole Dokument:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="De">
<head>
  <title>Titel</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Titel</h1>
  <p>Bitte erfasse Deine persönlichen Angaben:</p>
  <form role="form" action="/registrieren" method="post">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender">Frau</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender">Mann</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender">Anderes</label>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="usr">Vorname:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vorname" name="vorname">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="usr">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="usr">Strasse:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="strasse" name="strasse">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
                <label for="usr">PLZ:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="plz" name="plz">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="usr">Ort:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ort" name="ort">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" class="form-horizontal">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2"  for="usr">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" class="form-horizontal">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post some code to show what you've tried or are trying to do with your form.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about like this? Check out the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/registrieren" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label for="usr">Surname:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vorname" name="vorname">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label for="usr">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <label for="usr">Street:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="strasse" name="strasse">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically both postet form parts should stick together. The problem is that form-horizontal has to be given globally. Shall I post the entire html?